# Is there a way to use OpenTelemetry with Splunk without using a Collector using Java?

Tags: java, splunk, open-telemetry

I am working on some POC to use open telemetry with Splunk using Java. What I am looking for is to directly upload the open telemetry data to my local Splunk and later on in the Splunk cloud.

This was possible using the LightStep OpenTel Java Agent. I am looking for that same thing with Splunk.

```
java \
-Dotel.service.name=my-app \
-Dls.access.token=my-token \
-javaagent:lightstep-opentelemetry-javaagent.jar \
-jar my-java-app.jar
```

my-app : is the one i configured from LightStep (https://lightstep.com/)
my-token : is the token for my app also from the website.

I am hoping someone could point me to a similar POC / documentation related to this. With LightStep, the process was seamless to just directly connect and upload. Splunk documentation is suggesting to use a collector which is really my last option because I cannot install another app/software that runs in the background for my POC.

Thanks in advance!

---

This one worked and was able to upload to Splunk APM (not the regular Splunk)

```
java \
-Dotel.exporter.otlp.endpoint=https://ingest.<realm>.signalfx.com \
-Dsplunk.access.token=<token from splunk apm> \
-Dotel.service.name=app-service-name \
-Dsplunk.metrics.enabled=true \
-javaagent:splunk-otel-javaagent.jar \
-jar app.jar
```

Comment: I would use standard OTEL java agent - Lightstep and Splunk support OTLP protocol, so you don't need to use their legacy java agents anymore.

Comment: would you know if there is also a support for OTLP exporter (not using collector) using AppDynamics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation and use OTLP exporter which will be pointed to Splunk APM (of course us version, which already has OTLP support).